# Check if there are files in the source folder

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2014

I am using an SSIS package that removes the rows from the SQL table before importing. Before I run any tasks, I want to check if there is a file in the source folder. If the file exists, we will run our other SSIS tasks. Otherwise, we can complete our package without running any tasks.
I used the link below to configure the script task that checks the file exists in the source folder
http://www.techbrothersit.com/2013/07/ssis-how-to-check-if-file-exists-in.html

The problem I have is that the filename changes every day, and this example only works if we use the same file name all
the time.
Is there a way to do this to check that if .xlsx files exist in the source directory?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I used to use the script task approach, but i think a better approach (and this is something coming from someone that uses mainly c#) is to use a foreach loop. It basically translates to this... if your file exists, do everything inside the box otherwise you are done.

Comment: and use a mask of *.xlsx (hopefully you can refine that further) and move processed files to a processed folder

Answer (score 0):

we can do in different ways,
One way is to create 'Script Task' at the top, where you can 'look for the particular folder or file types ..etc and set one global variable'. and after Script task ends you can verify the Global variable value and make the necessary steps.

Example below, you can verify the condition as part of 'fx' function after script task.

[image]